# jfrog cli, how to return "creation date" during search

Tags: linux, jfrog-cli

I am trying to retrieve additional fields from **jfrog cli**:

```
./jfrog rt s --spec serach_old_spec.json
```

Having spec:

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "aql": {
                "items.find": {
                    "repo": "myrepo-deb-local",
                    "path": "pool",
                    "name": {"$match": "*.deb"}
                },
            },
        "limit": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

This request will actually work, returning files, but only **path** parameter. How can i return additionally **creation date** parameter?

I looked into https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-Usage, where i could find

> **fields** (Optional) There is a default set of fields for query output.
>   This parameter lets you specify a different set of fields that should
>   be included in the output

The problem, i can't understand how to use it inside **specs**, and there are no native parameter for **jfrog cli** https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SearchingFiles

Am i forced to implement it manually via REST calls ?